# Call multiple fields in another field at once based on type of the same model in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following models:

```
class Test1(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Test2(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Test3(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)
    test1 = models.ForeignKey(Test1, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    test2 = models.ManyToManyField(Test2, null = True, blank = True, related_name='test3s')
    test3 = models.ManyToManyField(Test3, blank=True, null=True, related_name='test3s')
    custom_values = CustomModel(m2m_fields=[test2, test3], fks=[test1])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

In the `custom_values` field I am passing a custom class for some functionality with the values of the same model. Now this is working correctly. But in some models there are more than five `m2m` and ten `fk` fields. So instead of specifying them every time is there any way for me to specify something like this? -

```
custom_values = CustomModel(m2m_fields='__all__', fks='__all__')
```

Here I would like to pass only m2m for m2m_fields and only foreignkey for fks.

Partial code for `CustomModel`

```
class CustomModel(BaseModel):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.m2m_fields = kwargs.pop("m2m_fields", [])
        self.fks = kwargs.pop("fks", [])

    #other methods

    def copy_fields(self, model):
        if isinstance(field, models.ForeignKey):
            #do something
        elif isinstance(field, models.ForeignKey):
            #do something
```

Comment: What is `CustomModel`? Can you share the code for it?

Comment: I have added partial code. Is that enough?

Comment: Why are you using model instance as other model attribute? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am actually extending `HistoricalRecords` class of `django-simple-history` to accommodate for m2m fields.

Comment: That `BaseModel` in `CustomModel` is `HistoricalRecords`

Comment: Ok, it makes sense, because `HistoricalRecords` does not inherit from `Model`. However `HistoricalRecords` already implements all required logic for collecting fields, it looks like you only need to override `copy_fields` and extend the dictionary of fields with customized m2m fields.

Comment: Yeah. I am actually sending the m2m fields as I have mentioned in the question. I just wanted to know if there is a way to send all of them at once instead of specifying each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django calls `contribute_to_class` for every attribute if this method is defined. Note that your class does not need to inherit from `models.Field` (tested in django 3.1.7 - though I didn't find any confirmation for it in documentation, so it may be an implementation detail):

```
class CustomModel:
    def __init__(self, *args, m2m_fields, fks, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.m2m_fields = m2m_fields
        self.fks = fks

    def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name, private_only=False):
        fields = list(chain(cls._meta.local_fields, cls._meta.local_many_to_many))
        if self.m2m_fields == '__all__':
            self.actual_m2m_fields = [x for x in fields if isinstance(x, models.ManyToManyField)]
        else:
            self.actual_m2m_fields = self.m2m_fields
        if self.fks == '__all__':
            self.actual_fks = [x for x in fields if isinstance(x, models.ForeignKey)]
        else:
            self.actual_fks = self.fks
        print(self.actual_m2m_fields)
        print(self.actual_fks)
```

Output:

```
[<django.db.models.fields.related.ManyToManyField: test2>, <django.db.models.fields.related.ManyToManyField: test3>]
[<django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey: test1>]
```

Comment: If I do not send that `__all__`, then wouldnt it be better if I did `self.m2m_fields = cls._meta.many_to_many`?

Comment: Docstring for `many_to_many`: `Private API intended only to be used by Django itself; get_fields() combined with filtering of field properties is the public API for obtaining this list.`. Unfortunately `get_fields` does not work in `contribute_to_class` because it can only be called after apps are loaded, so I needed to use `local_fields` and `local_many_to_many`.